# Running all tests in a leiningen project?

Tags: clojure, cider, testing

Is there a way, via `cider` or some other emacs extension, to run all of the tests in a leiningen project?

`cider` has the function `cider-test-run-tests` which attempts to just run the tests 
related to the code in the current buffer. That's fine, but often I want to run *all* of the tests in a project. (In fact, I'd like to run this all the time while editing.) I can't seem to find a simple way to say "find all of the tests in this project and run them."

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to do this currently in cider.

One would have to write a custom command to evaluate `clojure.tests/run-all-tests` (or `clojure.tests/run-tests` with a list of namespaces as arguments).

Answer (score 2):

there is an option to run all the tests in all the projects namespaces

`M-x cider-test-run-project-tests` or `C-c C-t C-p`

Here is the link to additional options for running tests

http://cider.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extended_workflow/#running-tests

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use [lein-test-refresh](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh) and `compile`.

This is a function that I use with it. I'm getting system notifications so I bury the buffer.

```el
(defun lein-test()
  (interactive)
  (compile "lein test-refresh")
  (pop-to-buffer
   (get-buffer "*compilation*"))
  (rename-buffer "*lein-test*")
  (delete-window))
```